# XMLHttpRequest cannot load No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin geoserver with php ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, geoserver, dc.leaflet.js

I know this may be a duplicate question.Please dont mar this as a duplicate . Im struck with this for the last two days. Please help me.

I have googled it . But i'm not able to find the solution for this issue.

What i'm trying to do na..

I have configured IIS-10 on my laptop.
PHP,MySQL,PostgreSQL too
 And also i have configured the same system with Geo server.

here im trying to access map that is created using shape files in Geo server. That is working fine.IM using leaflet.js for map functionalities

Then my issue is while im trying to add an event on ONCLICK , here im trying to call a WMS call in ajax. here im getting issue for that.
 please see the screen shot for the error [image]

My code for this is.

```
<?php
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost');  //I have also tried the * wildcard and get the same response
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
    header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 1000');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Content-Range, Content-Disposition, Content-Description');
//print_r($_GET);
$DistrictName="ALL";    // to show all kerala map with loc
$DistrictId=-1;         // to show all kerala map
if(isset($_GET) &&!empty($_GET)){
    if(isset($_GET['DistrictName'])&&!empty($_GET['DistrictName'])&&$_GET['DistrictName']!=""){
        $DistrictName=$_GET['DistrictName'];
    }else{
        $DistrictName="BMAP";   // to show all kerala map 
    }

    if(isset($_GET['DistrictId'])&&!empty($_GET['DistrictId'])&&$_GET['DistrictId']!=""){
        $DistrictId=$_GET['DistrictId'];
    }else{
        $DistrictId=0;          // to show all kerala map
    }
}
?>
<html>
<head> 
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/leaflet/leaflet.css"/>
 <script src="./js/leaflet/leaflet.js"></script>
 <script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/gis/CRS.Simple.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript"> 
 $(document).ready(function(){
    getDistrictBoundary('<?php echo $DistrictName; ?>');
}); 
 </script>
 <style>
    /*#mapid { height: 180px; }*/
 </style>

 </head>
 <body>
 <table width="100%" border="1">
    <tr>
        <td width="50%">
            <div id="mapid"  style="height: 600px;width: 100%; "></div>
        </td>

    </tr>
 </table>


 </body>
 <script> 
    var districtLayer="",Kerala_Layer_Group="";
    var map = L.map('mapid');
    function getDistrictBoundary(TxtDistrict){
      //alert(TxtDistrict);
      switch(TxtDistrict){ 
        case 'ALL':
                map.removeLayer(Kerala_Layer_Group);
                map.removeLayer(districtLayer);
                map.setView([10.54265308,76.13877106], 7); 
                districtLayer=L.tileLayer.wms("http://localhost:8081/geoserver/TAMS/wms/",{ // url
                layers: 'TAMS:Kerala_Layer_Group',// workspacce:layername
                format: 'image/png',
                transparent: true,      
                opacity: 0.7,
                zoom:10     
                }).addTo(map); 
            break; 
    } 

    map.on('click', function(e) {
        var url = getFeatureInfoUrl1( map, e.latlng, { 'info_format': 'application/jsonp', 'propertyName': 'NAME,AREA_CODE,DESCRIPTIO' } );
    getGson(url);
    });
    getGson=function(url){
       $.ajax({ 
            url: url,  
            crossDomain: true,
            dataType: 'application/jsonp',
            success: function() { alert("Success"); },
            error: function() { alert('Failed!'); }
        });
    };

    var geojsonLayerWells;
    function loadGeoJson(data) {

        $('#data').html("jshjhdjhdsj");
        /*geojsonLayerWells.addData(data);
        map.addLayer(geojsonLayerWells);
        map.addLayer(geojsonLayerWells);*/
    };



    function getFeatureInfoUrl1(map, latlng, params) { 
        var bounds = map.getBounds();
        var sw = bounds.getSouthWest();
        var ne = bounds.getNorthEast();
        var size = map.getSize();
        var point = map.latLngToContainerPoint(latlng, map.getZoom()); 
        return 'http://localhost:8081/geoserver/wms?' + 
        'request=GetFeatureInfo' +
        '&service=wms'+
        '&version=1.1.1'+
        '&layers=TAMS:district_boundary'+
        '&styles='+
        '&srs=EPSG:4326'+
        '&format=application/jsonp'+
        '&bbox='+ map.getBounds().toBBoxString()+
        '&width='+size.x +
        '&height='+size.y +
        '&query_layers=TAMS:district_boundary'+
        '&info_format=text/html'+
        '&feature_count=50'+
        '&x='+ point.x +
        '&y='+ point.y ; 

        } 
</script>
 </html>
```

Comment: enable cors in YOUR GEOSERVER

Comment: The CORS headers have to be present on your geo server.

Comment: @madalinivascu it is not working on my case i have followed  the [link](http://suite.opengeo.org/docs/latest/sysadmin/cors/index.html) please guide me to solve this issue.